Insta360 camera - what software and hardware for upload and basic editing
Hope someone can help.
I am about  to buy the insta360 GO 3S in order to record content for upload to youtube. I have some questions about hardware and software for basic video production.
A main reason for choosing this (Insta360) model (aside from the good reviews) is its ability to be used as a body cam while walking around, either worn on the chest using the magnetic ring on a neck lanyard, or on a cap peak... (I'm open to other camera suggestions if they can be used in the same way - I don't want one that can be used only on a selfie stick or gimbal or to be held in the hand etc)
Anyway, I will need to do some editing, inserting some text on screen maybe or some music before uploading to youtube. Nothing too fancy- like the basic on-screen texts and graphics one can see on these kind of walking style videos.
I have an old HP laptop which I've been looking to replace. It still works well enough for web surfing and so on but I realise its processing ability is unlikely to be enough.
What I would like is some recommendations for  basic editing software (pre-installed on a new PC is likely to be ok or not?), and minimum pc processing power (i.e. is (16GB RAM enough, cpu speed etc)... Also any other tips welcome on the interfacing between the Insta360 and the PC. Thank you in advance for any advice. Cheers!

Have you looked at the software that comes with the Insta360 camera yet. I think it does everything you need, as well as being able to cope with the 360 format, which many other editors cannot handle.
